# How to draw methods inside self message methods for UML sequence diagrams

Tags: oop, methods, model, uml, sequence-diagram

I'm trying to draw a sequence diagram for a code which looks like this:

```
Class Z:
   method y()

Class X:
   method w()

Class A inherits X & Z:
   method b() { 
       calls y()
       calls w()
   }

A a;
a.b()
```

At first I thought that I should draw a self message method like this:

```
     ┌─┐         
     │A│         
     └┬┘         
     ┌┴┐         
     │ │────┐    
     │ │    │ b()
     │ │<───┘    
     │ │         
     │ │         
     └┬┘    
     ┌┴┐     
     │A│         
     └─┘
```

but then I realised that this doesn't show how `b()` calls `y()`, so I considered this:

```
     ┌─┐          ┌─┐          ┌─┐
     │A│          │Z│          │X│
     └┬┘          └┬┘          └┬┘
     ┌┴┐    y()    │            │ 
     │ │ ─────────>│            │ 
     │ │           │            │ 
     │ │          w()           │ 
     │ │ ──────────────────────>│ 
     └┬┘           │            │ 
      │         return          │ 
      │<─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ │ 
     ┌┴┐          ┌┴┐          ┌┴┐
     │A│          │Z│          │X│
     └─┘          └─┘          └─┘
```

But then this one doesn't show `b()`. Is there a way I can draw this sequence diagram so that I can show both methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call of *b* seems to be made out of something associated to a class, so let say the initial caller is not important using a found message, then *y* and *w* are applied on the instance of *A* executing *b* whatever these operations are inherited, so :

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @driveaway fine, note the goal of an interaction is not to indicate on which class the operations are defined, but which instance send/receive messages

Comment: @qwerty_so I was speaking about the pseudo code, *from a class's instance* is strange for me, *by a class's instance* is may be better, but this is not what I wanted to say, there is no class so no instance nor operation too. Perhaps *made out of a class* is more appropriate ?

Comment: @qwerty_so in a lot of language a call can be done out of an operation, for instance in C++ or Python. *out of the scope of a class* ?

Comment: @qwerty_so I put *out of something associated to a class*. If the call is done in a static operation of a class there is no instance too, this is typically the case of the operation *main* in Java

Comment: Could be left that way, though I think _made from "somewhere"_ with the quotes would express it more generally.

Answer (score 1):

@bruno's answer is correct. He did not include the return message. Here is a diagram that I created with ZenUML (https://app.zenuml.com).

disclaimer: I am the author of ZenUML.

[image]